# Scrape multiple pages using Selenium VS SELE-detecting-site python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, user-agent, detect

I'm a month old with coding and a couple days old with Selenium.

This site is extremely stubborn and I managed to get it work one time, and no more, although the code wasn't changed. It keeps detecting me after the first page.

I tried a couple of methods to bypass:
[Start code]

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
```

These are the options -

```
option=webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument('--incognito')
option.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
option.add_argument('--profile-directory=Default')
option.add_argument('--disable-plugins-discovery')

browser=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=option)
```

A method I found to be potentially working:

```
for page in range(1,int(last_page),1):
    print(base_url+str(page)+base_search)
    browser.get(base_url+str(page)+base_search)
    grabber()
    browser.quit()
```

(The "grabber()" function is the working function that grabs the data I need)

Though - apparently once you quit the browser, and try to reopen another browser in the same session - the session crashes ([WinError 10061]). It could've been awesome since I get a new UA when a browser opens, and I get to have a page scraped as I am still undetected.

So each UserAgent gives me 1 page to scrape, and then it is detected and burnt.

Exploring here a little got me changing "call_function.js":

```
function getPageCache(opt_doc, opt_w3c) {
  var doc = opt_doc || document;
  var w3c = opt_w3c || false;
  //var key = '$cdc_asdjflasutopfhvcZLmcfl_';
  var key = '$newplacetostorecache_';
  if (w3c) {
    if (!(key in doc))
      doc[key] = new CacheWithUUID();
    return doc[key];
  } else {
    if (!(key in doc))
      doc[key] = new Cache();
    return doc[key];
  }
}
```

Didn't work.

So last I tried this last resort doomsday method:

```
import time
import string
import random

KEY_LEN = 20

def base_str():
    return (string.ascii_letters+string.digits)
def key_gen():
    keylist = [random.choice(base_str()) for i in range(KEY_LEN)]
    return ("".join(keylist))

for page in range(1,int(last_page),1):
    print(base_url+str(page)+base_search)
    browser.get(base_url+str(page)+base_search)
    grabber()
    option.add_argument('--user-agent=' + key_gen())
    print('user agent updated successfully')
```

And it worked!! This morning I was able to move forward about 12 pages from the total of about 20 (before it took too long to load a page and the session ended)

But a couple of hours later it didn't work anymore, I was again detected after grabbing the first page, only to run into the 2nd page's CAPTCHA

Are there any more methods I should definitely try to finally be able to scrape this site's data?